# uml condition too wide

Tags: tikz-uml

Now (means 4 hours ago) I started using `tikz-uml`, but I got a problem. I was doing the following seguence diagram,

[image]

Using this code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside, openright]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={17cm, 25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xstring} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlactor [x=2] {User}
        \umlobject [x=7] {Sys}
        \umlsdnode [dt=6]{Sys}
        \umlsdnode [dt=2]{User}
        \begin{umlfragment}[type=loop, label={pagato<importo}, inner xsep=5]
           \begin{umlcall}[dt=6, op={Importo (prezzo)}]{Sys}{User}
           \begin{umlcall}[dt=5, op={Pago (Moneta, Banconota)}, type=return]{User}{Sys} 
           \end{umlcall} 
           \end{umlcall} 
        \end{umlfragment}
        \begin{umlcall}[dt=6, op={Resto}]{Sys}{User}
        \end{umlcall}
        \end{umlseqdiag}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Sequenza \emph{Pagamento}}
    \label{fig:req1_5}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But, as you can see I got the `condition` to cover some part of my diagram.
What option(s) should I write to make enough space for it??

I mean also putting in above the diagram, near the word `loop` would be fine.

Comment: Thanks to the 2 people who corrected my code, as I forgot, when copy pasting, `\begin {document}` and `end{document}`; and some typo as well  :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest fix: increase the `inner xsep` if the `umlfragment` to `15`, say. This does increase the space on the right hand side as well, though.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlactor [x=2] {User}
        \umlobject [x=7] {Sys}
        \umlsdnode [dt=6]{Sys}
        \umlsdnode [dt=2]{User}
        \begin{umlfragment}[type=loop, label={pagato<importo}, inner xsep=15] % <-- increased inner xsep to 15
          \begin{umlcall}[dt=6, op={Importo (prezzo)}]{Sys}{User}
            %  \begin{umlcall}[dt=5, op={Pago (Moneta, Banconota)}, type=return]{User}{Sys}
            %  \end{umlcall} 
           \end{umlcall} 
        \end{umlfragment}
        \begin{umlcall}[dt=6, op={Resto}]{Sys}{User}
        \end{umlcall}
        \end{umlseqdiag}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

In order to move the label, you might have to edit `tikz-uml.sty`. I wouldn't normally recommend editing packages directly though. Another option is to copy the entire definition of the `umlfragment` environment to your preamble between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, change `\newenvironment` to `\renewenvironment`, and make the edit there instead.

Anyways, the line in question is line 4509 of `tikz-uml.sty` which just has the code

```
at (\tikzumlFragment@name-type.south west)
```

Change this to

```
at (\tikzumlFragment@name-type.north east)
```

Having done that, you might also want to add `inner ysep=2` to the `umlfragment` environment options, otherwise there isn't room for the label there.

Note that the nested `umlcall` environment for some reason caused an error when I tested on Overleaf, which is why it is commented out in the (somewhat reduced) code below. I have no idea why, if that didn't happen on your system, then I suppose there's no problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlseqdiag}
        \umlactor [x=2] {User}
        \umlobject [x=7] {Sys}
        \umlsdnode [dt=6]{Sys}
        \umlsdnode [dt=2]{User}
        \begin{umlfragment}[type=loop, label={pagato<importo}, inner xsep=5,inner ysep=2]
          \begin{umlcall}[dt=6, op={Importo (prezzo)}]{Sys}{User}
            %  \begin{umlcall}[dt=5, op={Pago (Moneta, Banconota)}, type=return]{User}{Sys}
            %  \end{umlcall} 
           \end{umlcall} 
        \end{umlfragment}
        \begin{umlcall}[dt=6, op={Resto}]{Sys}{User}
        \end{umlcall}
        \end{umlseqdiag}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should probably have asked for clarification first, as I'm really not sure this is what you meant, but ..

Comment: thank you, that's one way (the second one) to solve the problem. The first one was to make enough space for letting the `condition`, in my case `[pagato<importo]` so it doesn't cover up the arrow and the "_entity_" `user`.

Comment: @Fr3d Right, `inner xsep=15` might be enough for that, though you of course get extra space on the right side as well.

Comment: Luckily, this was the easy solution, next time I will try changing the line 4509 of `tikz-uml.sty`. Thanks